# Ideal generated by the Indeterminates of a Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I just want to clarify if the Ideal generated by $(X_1,...,X_n)$ in a polynomial ring $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ is just the set of polynomials without a constant term(except for zero).

i.e if $f=\sum_{(r_1,..,r_n)}r_{(r_1,..,r_n)}x^{(r_1,..,r_n)}$ is a polynomial without a constant term then each monomial is an element of $(X_1,...,X_n)$ hence $f$ would also be in $(X_1,...,X_n)$. On the other hand if $f\in (X_1,...,X_n)$, $f$ has no constant term because it is the sum of terms with at least 1 indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is true, in particular constant terms are units in the polynomial rings over a field, so no ideal of polynomial ring contain constants.